# Installation of Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, command-prompt, homestead

My whole log. I am fairly fresh to command prompt, I followed exactly the laravel documentation asked me to do but problems just keep popping up from no where.... Is my directory right? I normally run all command in my project directory but laravel asked me to "Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH so the homestead executable is found when you run the homestead command in your terminal." Please help.

```
~\Composer\vendor\bin>composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"

Changed current directory to ~/Roaming/Composer
    ./composer.json has been updated
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.2.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v3.1.0
    - Installation request for laravel/homestead ~2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/homestead[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.7, v2.0.8, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.2.0, v2.2.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.1.0
    - laravel/homestead v2.0.0 requires symfony/console ~2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.0, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.1, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.10, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.11, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.12, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.13, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.14, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.15, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.16, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.17, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.18, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.19, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.2, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.20, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.21, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.22, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.23, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.24, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.25, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.26, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.27, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.28, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.29, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.3, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.30, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.31, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.32, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.33, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.34, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.35, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.36, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.37, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.38, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.39, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.4, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.40, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.41, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.42, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.5, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.6, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.7, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.8, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.9, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.0, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.1, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.10, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.2, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.3, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.4, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.5, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.6, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.7, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.8, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.9, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.0, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.1, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.10, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.11, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.12, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.2, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.3, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.4, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.5, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.6, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.7, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.8, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.9, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.0, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.1, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.10, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.11, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.12, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.13, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.2, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.3, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.4, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.5, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.6, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.7, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.8, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.9, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.0, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.1, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.10, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.11, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.12, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.13, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.2, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.3, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.4, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.5, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.6, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.7, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.8, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.9, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.0, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.1, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.2, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.3, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.4, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.5, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.6, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[2.0.4, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[2.0.5, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[2.0.6, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[2.0.7, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.10, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.12, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.13, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.14, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.15, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.16, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.17, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.18, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.19, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.20, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.21, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.22, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.23, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.24, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.25, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.0.9, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.0, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.1, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.10, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.11, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.12, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.13, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.2, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.3, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.4, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.5, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.6, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.7, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.8, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.9, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.0, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.1, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.10, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.11, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.2, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.3, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.4, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.5, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.6, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.7, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.8, v3.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.9, v3.1.0].
    - Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v3.1.0) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.1.0].



Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Enter composer from my project directory, I get:

```
Composer version 1.1.1 2016-05-17 12:25:44

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help                     Display this help message
  -q, --quiet                    Do not output any message
  -V, --version                  Display this application version
      --ansi                     Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi                  Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction           Do not ask any interactive question
      --profile                  Display timing and memory usage information
      --no-plugins               Whether to disable plugins.
  -d, --working-dir=WORKING-DIR  If specified, use the given directory as working directory.
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose           Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  about           Short information about Composer
  archive         Create an archive of this composer package
  browse          Opens the package's repository URL or homepage in your browser.
  clear-cache     Clears composer's internal package cache.
  clearcache      Clears composer's internal package cache.
  config          Set config options
  create-project  Create new project from a package into given directory.
  depends         Shows which packages cause the given package to be installed
  diagnose        Diagnoses the system to identify common errors.
  dump-autoload   Dumps the autoloader
  dumpautoload    Dumps the autoloader
  exec            Execute a vendored binary/script
  global          Allows running commands in the global composer dir ($COMPOSER_HOME).
  help            Displays help for a command
  home            Opens the package's repository URL or homepage in your browser.
  info            Show information about packages
  init            Creates a basic composer.json file in current directory.
  install         Installs the project dependencies from the composer.lock file if present, or falls back on the composer.json.
  licenses        Show information about licenses of dependencies
  list            Lists commands
  outdated        Shows a list of installed packages that have updates available, including their latest version.
  prohibits       Shows which packages prevent the given package from being installed
  remove          Removes a package from the require or require-dev
  require         Adds required packages to your composer.json and installs them
  run-script      Run the scripts defined in composer.json.
  search          Search for packages
  self-update     Updates composer.phar to the latest version.
  selfupdate      Updates composer.phar to the latest version.
  show            Show information about packages
  status          Show a list of locally modified packages
  suggests        Show package suggestions
  update          Updates your dependencies to the latest version according to composer.json, and updates the composer.lock file.
  validate        Validates a composer.json and composer.lock
  why             Shows which packages cause the given package to be installed
  why-not         Shows which packages prevent the given package from being installed
```

Comment: Do you have any other packages installed globally?

Comment: well not quite sure what that means. but I recently surfed and installed notify/sweetalert2 from codecourse, vagrant, virtualbox, that should be basically it..

Comment: Have you run `composer global require <vendor/package` before? It seems like `laravel/homestead`'s `symfony/console` dependency is conflicting with the currently installed `symfony/console` (which is most probably installed as a dependency of another package.

Comment: here https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead  
for global installation just clone the repo
`git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead`  
for local one   
`composer require laravel/homestead --dev`  
just curious where did you find composer with global?

Comment: Thanks +vitr, I actually tried this global one before but it popped out error... somehow I tried again after seeing your message it works suddenly... What a miracle.. But by now I am still not sure where the problem is but thanks anyways it works now.

Answer (score 3):

> It seems like laravel/homestead's symfony/console dependency is conflicting with the currently installed symfony/console (which is most probably installed as a dependency of another package)
>
> *[Installation of Homestead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581884/installation-of-homestead#comment62652751_37581884) by Doom5*

As long as the package cause a conflict, you're not able to install it - you need to resolve the requirements first. The [`require`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require)-command doesn't do this automatically. Here's a workaround, that worked at least for me:

#### Method 1

**1. Add the failing package to `composer.json`:**

This could also be done by hand, however composer does this already for us with the `--no-update` option, which *"Disables the automatic update of the dependencies"* (i.e., add the package to `composer.json`, but don't install it):

```
composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0" --no-update
```

**2. Reinstall the affected packages:**

Having `"laravel/homestead": "~2.0"` now in `composer.json`, we can resolve the dependencies, and install them into `~/.composer/vendor`.

```
composer global update
```

To update only the packages that cause the conflict, you could use the [`prohibits`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#prohibits) and [`depends`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#depends) commands, to get packages that are blocking the given package.

---

#### Method 2

<s>Another solution is to require the dependencies directly. However, this would not really solve the issue...</s>

```
composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0" "symfony/console=~2.0"
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch man, I was struggling with this for 3 days now and nearly put me behind on my project. Thank you SO MUCH!!!!